# Microsoft SQL lambda: Combining columns for searching

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a table like so:

```
ID | FirstName | LastName |  
---------------------------
 1 |   Kathy   |  Gray    |
```

Then I have a search box that will provide a single string. The string could be the user's first name, last name, *both* first name and last name separated by a space. Partial matches should also work. "Kath Gra" for example.

Using Entity Framework lambda expressions, how can I use the given string to search the database for the above criteria?

This is an existing application, and here's the filter as it is currently written:

```
var students = Students.Where(e => e.FirstName.Contains(searchString) ||
                                     e.LastName.Contains(searchString);
```

Obvious problem being that "Kathy Gray" doesn't exist in either column by itself. Normally, I would just create a new model with a `FullName` field and search against that, but in this particular case, such a modification would be difficult.

Thanks!

EDIT: code was simplified from original, but I left a confusing variable name. Fixed.

Comment: have you tried running this by assigning it to a new variable 
`var enrollment enrollments.Where(e => e.FirstName.Contains(searchString) ||
                                     e.LastName.Contains(searchString);` where is enrollments defined..?

Comment: If you want to also search for "Gray Kathy", you should split the string and search for each one independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to concatenate First Name and Last Name in your lamba expression

```
enrollments = enrollments.Where(e => (e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: The generated sql might look like select * from enrollments where FirstName + ' ' + Last Name like @serachString

Comment: No, I didn't. And that appears to work great. Thanks!